# Angular 4 - Code response value is undefined

Tags: angular

I am loading data from a json file in a html table,

This is the method in my component file:

```
getParticulars(){
        this._particularService.getParticulars().subscribe(
            result => {
                console.log("code: ", result.code);
                if(result.code != 200){
                    console.log("Respuesta: ", result);
                }else{
                    console.log("Si tengo datos para particulares");
                    this.particulars = result.data;
                }

            },
            error => {
                console.log(<any>error);
            }
        );
    }
```

This is the method in my service file:

```
getParticulars(){
    return this._http.get(this.url).map(res => res.json());
}
```

This is the file json:

```
[
    {
      "code": "200"
    },
    {
      "field1": "1",
      "field2": "2",
      "field3": "3",
      "field4": "31/12/9999",
      "field5": "4,
      "field6": "5",
      "field7": "7",
      "field8": "8",
      "field9": "9",
      "field10": "10"
    },
    {
      "field1": "11",
      "field2": "12",
      "field3": "11/07/2017",
      "field4": "13",
      "field5": "14",
      "field6": "15",
      "field7": "16",
      "field8": "17",
      "field9": "18",
      "field10": "19"
    }
  ]
```

The problem is, the response service code (result.code) value is undefined, but I don't know Why?

```
console.log("code: ", result.code);
```

If the result code is undefined, I am going to access in the condicion, when the result code is different to 200, but it shows the json file correct in console  browser.

```
console.log("Respuesta: ", result);
```

Thanks,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**`result`** is an array, so you should specifiy the index,

```
console.log("code: ", result[0].code);
```

Answer (score 0):

result[0].code will do the trick, which is zeroth index of an result array